# How to restrict user to upload image in ink file picker?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, filepicker.io

I am using ink file picker to pick single iamge.
I want to restrict user to upload image with width 100 and height 300.
If image is not in proper size then send error message.
How to restrict user?

Answer (score 0):

you can check image size using `FileReader()` and `jquery`

```
function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function(_file) {
        image.src    = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function() {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name,
                s = ~~(file.size/1024) +'KB';
          if(w!=100 || h!=100){
            alert("invalid height or width");

          }

            $('#uploadPreview').append('<img src="'+ this.src +'"> '+w+'x'+h+' '+s+' '+t+' '+n+'<br>');
        };
        image.onerror= function() {
            alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
        };      
    };

}
$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if(this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if(F && F[0]) for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) readImage( F[i] );
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Multiple image upload with preview by Roko C.B.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>
```

JS BIN example [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/oTAtIpA/724/)